# How do I group graphics I draw in a winform using C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I got a problem while drawing graphics in a winform using C#. There're several graphics on my form and I've already been able to select and move each of them. Now I'm working on this function that enable drawing a rectangle and all inner graphics will be selected. Then I can move this rectangle together with inner graphics. By clicking or selecting something else, the rectangle will disappear (or say, destroyed) and the inner graphics separated again. Just like what we can do to the icons on the desktop. 
Have you got any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Get x,y coords at mouse down & mouse up
2. loop through all graphics on your form, finding those whose top left & bottom right are within those bounds. Remember  them in a list (including their current x,y coords)
3. so far, so easy, now, how to group them ? I would suggest that you temporarily create a panel behind them (use z-order to put it behind them); perhaps shade it in some was to indicate that it is a section
4. wait on your next mouse down, if it it outside of the section, cancel the selection (and remove the section panel) and quit
5. Do you need to track mouse move events? I think that mouse up is enough. When you get mouse up, loop through the list which you saved in 2) and adjust the x,y coords of each dragged component by the amount of change between the drag panels initial position & its end position.
6. Remove the drag panel

That should do it. HTH.